# Trouble uninstalling .net framework 4

Tags: windows-7, installation, 64-bit, uninstall, .net-framework

I wish to install Liquid XML Studio which requires .Net framework version 4.

I installed it yesterday and it worked fine without complaining but this screwed my Microsoft Management studio and since then I am trying to uninstall it. And keeps complaining about the compatibility. Says:

> Blocking Issues:
>
> This setup program requires an x86 computer. It cannot be installed on
>   x64 or IA64 computers. For more information, see the [Readme](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=164156) file.

Why did it install on a x64 then? How can I uninstall this please?

P.S. I get this when I try uninstalling .net framework 4 client profile or .net framework 4 extended ?

Also, I still can't run the xml studio .. it complains about missing .net framework 4!
and when I try to install a fresh one, it says that .net framework is already installed on computer!

Comment: What exactly is blocking? Management Studio? If so, which version? What files did you download? Did you try removing .NET with the removal tool? The .NET Framework cleanup tool is available from this link: http://techdows.com/2009/07/uninstall-and-repair-net-framework-with.html

Comment: Have you tried "Repair Mode" of installation?

Comment: Thanks Randolph West, the tool worked ... I could uninstall the .net framework 4.. and sql server management studio is back ! Thanks :) .. you might want to answer the question and I will accept it ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would remove the .NET installation with the .NET Framework cleanup tool, available from http://techdows.com/2009/07/uninstall-and-repair-net-framework-with.html.

Comment: Thanks ! Sorry do not have the privilige to vote you up

Comment: That's ok. When you have more rep, you're welcome to revisit the answer :-)